# Using PHP to Execute cURL to send Push Notification

Tags: php, curl, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm attempting to send a cURL command to send a push notification. I'm pretty new to cURL and cannot seem to get the command to run.

Here is the cURL command line:

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=AAAAVD27CWY:APA91bE7YdKYiqTmQhErf0E3gm8lbgNt2KP5-xPQf83V7m8eKsa0ljktOLiGyzzrP0uxVNBHC6cyuJAPejkTyNl1DnoxcajesLvGXIzq3YR1l-wiFvoivRmIUkDvThTsKCJkZMomhEPp" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"fr1l051Pczw:APA91bGkyuA6iKMP6oICJ8NweijQpWTWGuo-inqvpF5-Mety0D7oL_ppvevKKdWPxIo7ev_v5sAWbprk7pEg8kz3cNCivipL9RCR3XlA1caBtahsRtnANZpaU-KYnsdjcGY3Q51xN1ny\"]}"
```

and here is the PHP cURL I'm trying to execute:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"registration_ids\":[\"fr1l051Pczw:APA91bGkyuA6iKMP6oICJ8NweijQpWTWGuo-inqvpF5-Mety0D7oL_ppvevKKdWPxIo7ev_v5sAWbprk7pEg8kz3cNCivipL9RCR3XlA1caBtahsRtnANZpaU-KYnsdjcGY3Q51xN1ny\"]}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: key=AAAAVD27CWY:APA91bE7YdKYiqTmQhErf0E3gm8lbgNt2KP5-xPQf83V7m8eKsa0ljktOLiGyzzrP0uxVNBHC6cyuJAPejkTyNl1DnoxcajesLvGXIzq3YR1l-wiFvoivRmIUkDvThTsKCJkZMomhEPp";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: \"application/json\"";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

I'm running this with Google's Firebase Cloud Messaging.

I can execute the command on my server, so I know at least that works.

Running UBUNTU 16.04 and Apache.
I am running SSL on the server and have tried adding:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
```

Still no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use the below PHP Curl Request

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"registration_ids\":[\"fr1l051Pczw:APA91bGkyuA6iKMP6oICJ8NweijQpWTWGuo-inqvpF5-Mety0D7oL_ppvevKKdWPxIo7ev_v5sAWbprk7pEg8kz3cNCivipL9RCR3XlA1caBtahsRtnANZpaU-KYnsdjcGY3Q51xN1ny\"]}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: key=AAAAVD27CWY:APA91bE7YdKYiqTmQhErf0E3gm8lbgNt2KP5-xPQf83V7m8eKsa0ljktOLiGyzzrP0uxVNBHC6cyuJAPejkTyNl1DnoxcajesLvGXIzq3YR1l-wiFvoivRmIUkDvThTsKCJkZMomhEPp",
    "content-type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: That did it.Thank you very much!